# How do I run a Batchfile in fore screen

Tags: batch-file

I have an application, and want to start it in Media center, when media center is in full screen, and i open this tile, the batch file opens my application in background.
How do i get this in front, that it open on the media Center.

Comment: Thats probably something you need to code from the application rather than the batch file.

Comment: You can also create an generic applicaiton accepting an executable path on the command line. With dot net, the Process class allows you to start applications and get their process id's. Then you could use the windows api to bring the window to the front. Advantage is that you can reuse this code, and do not need to change the app code you are launching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick approach coded in C# would be:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(args[0]);
            if (process != null) SetForegroundWindow(process.Handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this example ofcourse needs error handling and validation of the arguments. Optionally you can develop support for working folders if you need so.

Use the next line in your batch to invoke the application

```
Example.exe "c:\sample\path\app.exe"
```

Comment: in my wpf application i dont have Static void Main(string[] args)?

Comment: This example was for an 'helper' executable that should be developed in the console application template.  If you want to implement this into your WPF application, you should use the code but place it in the startup method of your WPF application. The usage of the dllimport and the setforeground window would be the same except that you should get the process id from the current process instead of a new process.